# How to handle extremes in lab results

Tags: r, data-wrangling

My question is how to handle extremes in lab results?

There are often some extreme values that exceed the measurement range in the laboratory inspection results. How can I count the overall results in a column with measurable values that are beyond the measurement range? My approach is to directly define the extreme values that can be measured, and I don't know if this is correct, or if there is a more rigorous way to deal with these data.

for example:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 3 | **>50** |
| 4 | **<2** |
| 5 | 25 |
| .. | .. |
| .. | .. |

Suppose I want to calculate the mean, standard deviation of value, How to handle the values of id 3 & 4 ? Just set them to the extreme value 50 & 2 ?

Thank you!

P.S.

I only know R language

Comment: You can certainly set them to something like 50.1 or 1.9 but without known those exact values you won't get accurate `sd` calculations on this set of values

Comment: If you don't want to set an arbitrary threshold, have you thought about using anomaly analysis?